# prove $d(f,g):=\sup_{x \in X} d(f(x),g(x))$ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$,$Y$ be metric space. define $A_b:=\{f:X \to Y | f(X) \text{ is bounded}\}$. for all $f,g \in A_b$, prove $d(f,g):=\sup_{x \in X} d(f(x),g(x))$ is finite.

Here is my attempt:

Since $f,g \in A_b$, for all $x,y \in X ,\enspace \sup \{d(f(x),f(y))\}$ and $\sup \{d(g(x),g(y))\}$ is finite.

Now I have, for all $x,y \in X$,  $$\sup \{d(f(x),f(y))\}+\sup \{d(g(x),g(y))\} = \sup \{d(f(x),f(y))+d(g(x),g(y))\} \in \mathbb{R}$$

Then I would like to apply triangle inequality to the equation above to have $\sup \{d(f(x),g(x))\}$ is finite. i.e., I would like to use
$$ d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$$
but we can't promise there exists a point that $M \in f(X) \cap g(X)$, thus I'm stuck here...

Any hints or solution will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is meant by $\sup\{d(f(x),f(y))\}$?  Why do you want a point in $f(X)\cap g(X)$?

Comment: For any $B\subseteq Y$ and $y \in Y$, define $\operatorname{diam}(B,y)=\sup\{d(b,y):b\in B\}$. Then it is easy to prove that $B$ is bounded if and only if $\operatorname{diam}(B,y)<\infty$ for any $y\in Y$. Using this, fix your favorite $y \in Y$ and check that $$d(f(x),g(x))\leq d(f(x),y)+d(y,g(x))\leq\operatorname{diam}(f(X),y)+\operatorname{diam}(g(X),y)$$ holds for all $x \in X$. Then the desired claim follows by taking supremum over $x\in X$

Comment: hello! since$ f(x),f(y) \in Y$, this ''d'' is the metric from metric space Y

Comment: I know but what are you taking a sup over?  Do you mean $\sup_{x\in X, y\in X} \{d(f(x),f(y))\}$?

Comment: yes, exactly, sorry for confusion!

Comment: But then I disagree with your claim $$\sup_{x\in X, y\in X} [d(f(x),f(y))] + \sup_{x \in X, y\in X} [d(g(x),g(y))] = \sup_{x\in X, y\in Y}[d(f(x),f(y)) + d(g(x),g(y))]$$

Comment: @ Michael you might be right,  I was using a general formula $sup A + sup B = sup A+B$

Comment: @Sangchul Lee, thanks! I got that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f(X) \cup g(X)$ is also bounded.